# Getting 'nan' when trying to take average of values within a selected column?

Tags: pandas, classification

Homework help: What's the average knowledge in "classification" of those MSBA students that know both SQL and Java?

Trying to get the average of the selected column with the conditions outlined. I get 'nan' when trying to run my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("cleaned_survey.csv", index_col=0)
df.drop(['ProgSkills','Languages','Expert'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df.Classification[(df['Program']=='MSBA')&(df['SQL']==1)&(df['Java']==1)].mean()
```

I expect to get the average for the classification column with the conditions that I included.

Picture of sample data: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfMKb.png

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have, either only NaNs or now records under that criteria for John.

Could also be that column does not have the proper `dtype`.
Try `df['hw'] = df['hw'].astype(int)`

Comment: I tried that and got an error message: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'MSIS'

Comment: Yeap, that means you have a row in column `hw` with value `MSIS`.
Check your data for more string values rather than integers, for example use `df['hw'].value_counts()`